# Como cerrar y abrir otro formulario en c#

Tags: c#, formularios

Como puedo hacer para que cuando mi primer formulario Login ya verifique al usuario, que le muestre otro formulario Principal del cual en ese formulario al apretar el botón cerrar haga que se cierre todo el programa

Yo ya he visto algún que otro video tutorial donde pude hacer el llamado a otros formularios y ocultar el formulario Login, pero cuando quiero cerrar todo el programa con 1 boton que esta en el formulario Principal, solo se cierra ese formulario y el programa se sigue ejecutando

código del formulario Login

```
private void coseandopen()
        {
            Principal cerrar = new Principal();
            this.Hide();
            cerrar.Show();
        }
```

//código del botón del formulario Principal

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando te autenticas y verificas que la clave y el usuario son correctos deberías hacer algo como esto:

```
//Botón autenticar

Principal frm = new Principal();
txtClave.Clear();
txtUsuario.Clear();
this.Hide();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Construyes el formulario y borras los **TextBox** de la clave y el usuario, ya que aunque escondas el formulario de login estos **TextBox** no se borran, lo cual puede conllevar problemas serios de seguridad, después ocultas el formulario de login y muestras el otro.

Para cerrar la aplicación completa en el botón salir pones:

```
Application.Exit();
```

Y terminará la ejecución completa del programa.

Comment: Gracias, he seguido tu consejo de colocar el .clear(); en una parte del codigo y ahora lo veo mucho mejor que antes